# ng-click and ng-change not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm making a html code with `angular.element(document).find(id).html(code)` that there is a ng-click and ng-change in `code` var. When it writes the html code, it is supposed to work correctly, analysing the html code generated:

Code generated using angular.element:

```
<a style="cursor:pointer" title="Atualizar" ng-click="atualizarHistorico(303456)"><i class="mdi-action-autorenew small"></i></a>
```

But when I click in the button, it is not executing the function `atualizarHistorico()`

I'm generating something like this:

```
var return = '<a style="cursor:pointer" title="Atualizar" ng-click="atualizarHistorico(303456)"><i class="mdi-action-autorenew small"></i></a></div>';
angular.element(document).find('#' + id).html(return);
```

**Only in this situation is not working**, that the html code with `ng-click` and `ng-change` are generated by **`angular.element`**.

Comment: Does it work when using jQuery ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you must append the HTML, you need to get access to the `$compile` service. Then compile the HTML, and link it to the scope that has the functions you want to execute:

```
$scope.atualizarHistorico = function(...

var return = // HTML
var compiledAndLinked = $compile(return)($scope);
angular.element(document).find('#' + id).html(compiledAndLinked);
```